# Absolutely true centred background image

Tags: css, background, background-image

oI have a site where a centred background image plays a vital part in a homepage animation.

The background centres great until the browser window cannot fit in the width of the site, at which point the background kind of left aligns.

This is my body code:

```
body {
line-height:1;
margin:0px auto;
padding:0px;
background:#90a830 url(img/bg.png) no-repeat center top;
}
```

The image popups shoot out from the correct place on the bg image. Try making the browser window smaller and you will see what i mean, the bg moves out of alignment.

thanks

Andy

Comment: why don't you try creating an overlay ? and set the z-index to a value less than the elements on top and also set the opacity to around 0.6. should help

Comment: use a fixed background

Comment: Until we can see the animation it's hard to help. Do you have a live link. Media queries would seem to be the answer through.

Answer (score 0):

Set the background left to 50% and the background margin-left to be 0 minus the width of the background. That way it will always show the horizontal center of the image in the horizontal center of the browser window.

See my JSbin demo [here](http://jsbin.com/ruliw/5/edit?html,css,output). I reused your image so it looks weird with the other example images below!

CSS:

```
body {
  line-height:1;
padding:0px;
  margin-left:-575px; /* half your background image width */
  background:#90a830 url(http://www.apb-media.co.uk/uploads/background.jpg) 50% top;
}
```

Comment: guymid i tried your solution first and it didnt work, it pushed the whole site off the page to the left.

Comment: i added live link to original question, maybe that will better explain it.

Answer (score 0):

With the code you posted, the background image will always be centered on screen. On small screens, you want the houses to be center-screen; but this can only happen if the houses are in the center of the image. So my recommendation, if possible, would be to have the same amount of green grass on each side of the image, so that the houses are in the center of the image. Then you won't run into this problem.

If you can't change the image and the center of the houses is, say, 240px to the left of center of the image, you could center the houses on screen with something like this:

```
body {
    background: url(bg.png) calc(50% + 240px) 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Or perhaps you could just use that inside `@media` rules for smaller screens if you don't want the image to look off center on wider screens.

Comment: hi Ralph thanks for the help but the code supplied didnt help, it moved the bg image but when screen got small the image started to move again.

Comment: i added live link to original question, maybe that will better explain it.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. It works perfectly for me on your site. What browser are you using?